# Is there a way to make child posts inherit parent post terms?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a few custom posts that go from Parent to great grand children. I assign the parent post a term from a custom taxonomy that I would like for all of the child posts to inherit. Is there a way to do this? Otherwise, I will have to apply the term to each post, which will be a very daunting task.

Comment: Research [this results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bsave_post+%2Bpost_type+%2Bparent+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks for the suggestion. However, I scoured the web before I posted here and I did not find a solution.

Comment: Ok. It's better if you add this kind of info to your questions, so you won't receive suggestions that you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I found the above code useful and have tweaked it so that it works on save of the parent to the children, in case that's useful to anyone (it seems more in line with OPs use case, as every time they add a parent term it will trickle down on save)

```
function set_child_terms( $post_id, $post ) {

$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post_id,
    'post_type'   => 'product', 
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any' 
);
$children = get_children( $args );


    if ( 'publish' === $post->post_status && $children > 0 ) {
       
       foreach( (array) $children as $child) {

        if(!empty($child)){
            $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post->post_type );
            foreach ( (array) $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
                if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
                    $termArr = array_map(create_function('$obj', 'return $obj->term_id;'), $terms);
                    $tmp = wp_set_object_terms( $child->ID, $termArr, $taxonomy, false ); // set to true if you don't want to overwrite/reset existing terms
                }
            }
        } }
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'set_child_terms', 100, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create the post from the wordpress ui just add this to your functions.php and it will do what you need:

```
function set_parent_terms( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( 'publish' === $post->post_status && $post->post_parent > 0 ) {
        $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);

        if(!empty($parent)){
            $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $parent->post_type );
            foreach ( (array) $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $parent->ID, $taxonomy );
                if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
                    $termArr = array_map(create_function('$obj', 'return $obj->term_id;'), $terms);
                    $tmp = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $termArr, $taxonomy, true );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_parent_terms', 100, 2 );
```

if you are creating your post using `wp_insert_post` then i dont really know how to make it work